# Using JavaScript ID in a jQuery expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a td defined as below

```
<td id="Level3<%=rsProducts.getString(1)%>">
```

I am using JavaScript to get the id of the td as below.

```
var objAccessLevelIndustry3 = document.getElementsByName("Level3"+product);
```

I am getting the id correctly. But I am unable to use it in a jQuery expression. I am trying the following, but it does not work.

```
$(#'objAccessLevelIndustry3').show();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The `#` needs to be part of the quoted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#Level3"+product).show();
```

and skip the document.getElementsByName() - which should probably be document.getElementById anyway, but you don't need it in jQuery.

Comment: actually using `document.getElementById` will make the operation much faster. Code: `$(document.getElementById("#Level3" + product)).show();`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

It has syntax error

```
  $(objAccessLevelIndustry3).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this

$(objAccessLevelIndustry3).show();**